# Spinnaker : How to pull Jenkins build artifact

Tags: spinnaker

How to pull the build artifact of a Jenkins job from Spinnaker? I have linked Spinnaker with Jenkins and able to view jobs. I want to pull the artifact once the Jenkins job is completed from Spinnaker and push it to PCF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you can download files as part of a spinnaker pipeline without extending it with a new type of trigger (this would require a PR, and an update when it's merged & released). In the meantime, you can push your artifact to some kind of artifacts repository at the end of the jenkins job, and watch the repository for changes using a spinnaker trigger (such as a docker registry for instance, but you could probably achieve the same with git)